# Laravel explain me how working query

Tags: laravel

I have a problem with query on laravel.
Please show me how it work, because I can't understand doc.
For example, I have VideoController.php and I have some data from forms:

```
$gall = array(
            'name' => Input::get('name'),
            'user_id' => Auth::id()
            );
```

now I want to add this data to DB, but I don't know how to call to create function in model (and how this function should look).
And please explain me, how I should select data from database and display it on view, where for example user_id = 15;

Answer (score 0):

In your `VideoController.php` file you should have a method to store the data, which you should post your data to through a form or something.

In a view, this form should look something like this:

```
{{ Form::open(['route' => 'video.store']) }} <!-- check your routes to see if video.store exists, you'll get an error otherwise --> 

     ... form elements ...

    {{ Form::submit('Submit') }}

{{ Form::close() }}
```

In your `store()` function you should have code similar to this

```
$video = new Video(); // if your video model is Video.php
$video->name = Input::get('name');
$video->user_id = Auth::id();
$video->save();
```

And if you want to display data, i.e. your video index or something, in your `VideoController.php` file, in the `index()` function:

```
$videos = Video::all();

return View::make('video.index', array('videos' => $videos));
```

then in your view

```
@foreach($videos as $video)

    {{ $video->name }}

@endforeach
```

Comment: I want only video where useR_id = 12

Comment: `$video = Video::where('user_id',12)->get();`